# Where do I submit bug for summary fields extension?

Tags: issues, summaryfields

Where can I submit the bug for the Summary Fields extension?

It seems that the Summary Fields extension has an issue with Relative Dates. In *Advanced Search* I choose the **Date of Last Contribution** as **Last 60 days including today**. When I go back to saved Smart Group later, the *relative date* is replaced with *fixed date* (when the group was created).

[image]

Comment: We did a bunch of work on ensuring that relative dates get saved as relative dates. I think the outcome was an extension, but objective was to improve on that and get it pushed back to core. not sure how easily it would apply to Summary Fields but may give someone a head start.

Comment: What extension are you referring to?

Comment: hasn't been published yet as still in QA phase afaik

Comment: if it gets pushed as a PR to core I will update this with JIRA ticket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Github repo for this extension lives here:
https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.sumfields
[and has an Issues tab]

Comment: Thanks for answering KarinG. Question is raised (and answered) via github: https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.sumfields/issues/24

Comment: @Jamie I think the issue is still open as the bug still persists on 4.7.14.

Answer (score 2):

As KarinG pointed out, best way is probably to raise the issue in GitHub: https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.sumfields
In general, if someone created and shared an extension it does not automatically mean they will fix all bugs you report. It might mean they come back to you and ask if you would fund the fix. Just to manage your expectations :-)....